# R markdown format title - pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I'm sure this is already out there but I can't seem to find it. How can I change the font size and spacing for the title in an R markdown document compiled as a pdf?

Thanks!

Comment: LaTeX, though exactly how varies a bit on the context.

Comment: @alistaire - you mean to incorporate that in the .tex document that I have setup (based on another post from you, I believe) already in my header?

Comment: For the font size, for example, you could do something like this in the yaml: `title: \scriptsize{My Title}`. For the spacing, do you mean you want different spacing between lines for a multiline title?

Comment: You can put LaTeX code directly into the non-code-chunk portions of an Rmd if you're knitting to PDF. Editing the intermediate .tex is a bad idea as the workflow is not reproducible.

Comment: @eipi10 Is there a way to specify the scriptsize, for example, to 15pt?

Comment: You can set the fontsize globally within the YAML at beginning of the rmarkdown document. For example, `fontsize: 15pt`. If you want to change the fontsize temporarily, there's a latex command to set a specific font size, but it's probably better to use the various named sizes (e.g., `\normalsize`, `\Large`, `\scriptsize`), because these are always relative to the baseline font size for your document. [See here](http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html) for details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you want the document to look, but here are some ways to control spacing and fontsize with `Latex` tags. In the `rmd` document below:

1. The initial `\vspace{5cm}` adds space above the first line of the title. `\vspace{0.5cm}` adds space between the two lines of the title.
2. `\LARGE` and `\Large` give different font sizes on different lines of the title.
3. `|` at the beginning of each line of the title allows a multi-line title.
4. If you want a separate cover page, `\newpage` at the beginning of the main document will start the main document text on a new page after the title page.

---

```
---
title: | 
  | \vspace{5cm} \LARGE My Title is really long and takes up several lines of text
  | \vspace{0.5cm} \Large My Title is really long and takes up several lines of text
author: "eipi10"
date: "5/16/2017"
output: pdf_document
---

\newpage

Document text here.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do exactly this but for HTML output?

Comment: `\LARGE` is a switch and does not take an argument, so it should be `{\LARGE ...}`. Without starting a new paragraph after it, the spacing to the following line will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer, but without the braces (which show up in the rendered version).

Answer (score 2):

For a *smaller* title section, the following may be helpful. It builds on eipi10's answer but with two modifications:

1. the `vspace{}` commands include negative values to shrink white space
2. the fontsize code uses the more cumbersome `begin{}` and `end{}` syntax because, with simpler code like `\normalsize{}`, I found extraneous braces appeared around the title, name, etc.

---

```
---
title: \vspace{-0.75cm} \begin{normalsize} My Title \end{normalsize} \vspace{-0.5cm}
author: \begin{normalsize} My Name \end{normalsize}
date: \begin{normalsize} 5/16/2017 \end{normalsize}
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: `\normalsize{...}` is incorrect syntax. Such font commands are switches and don't take an argument, so it would have to be `{\normalsize ...}`. However as you correctly observed, this will result in incorrect spacing if no new paragraph is started afterwards.